# Drawing getting pixelated in iOS

Tags: ios, uikit, core-graphics, cgcontext, cglayer

I am working on a drawing application, I am drawing into **CGlayers**, I am creating a CGlayer this way

```
-(void)drawRect
{

    if(self.DrawingLayer == nil)
    {
           CGFloat scale = self.contentScaleFactor;
           CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width * scale, self.bounds.size.height * scale);
           CGLayerRef layer = CGLayerCreateWithContext(context, bounds.size, NULL);
           CGContextRef layerContext = CGLayerGetContext(layer);
           CGContextScaleCTM(layerContext, scale, scale);
           self.DrawingLayer = layer;
    }

    CGContextDrawLayerInRect(context,rectSize, self.newDrawingLayer);
    CGContextDrawLayerInRect(context, self.bounds, self.DrawingLayer );
}
```

Now as my drawing Canvas can be dynamically increased/decreased, whenever user performs any of the actions , I create one more layer and store the previous drawing on to the new CGlayer
this way

```
-(void)canvasIncreased
{               
      rectSize = self.bounds
      CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

      CGFloat scale = self.contentScaleFactor;
      CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width * scale, self.bounds.size.height * scale);
      CGLayerRef layer = CGLayerCreateWithContext(context, bounds.size, NULL);
      CGContextRef layerContext = CGLayerGetContext(layer);
      CGContextScaleCTM(layerContext, scale, scale);
      self.newDrawingLayer = layer;

      CGContextDrawLayerInRect(layerContext, self.bounds, self.DrawingLayer);
      self.DrawingLayer = nil;
 }
```

Everything works fine, but what happens is that whenever I draw something then increase canvas size, the again draw, then increase canvas size, then again draw and so on,

then, my previous drawing is getting pixelated, here is the image

[image]

Comment: what happens if you scale a graphics file in photoshop and co? they also get pixellated. Only solution is to redraw the vectors, otherwise pixelation must happen (interpolation!)

Comment: Hello @Vector, what do you mean by "redraw the vectors", can you please elaborate

Comment: I assumed your drawing code produces paths. to these i referred as vectors. if you resize you'll need to recall the same commands to draw just for the new size and then it is not pixelated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting pixelated strokes while drawing UIBezeirPath in CGlayer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21906687/getting-pixelated-strokes-while-drawing-uibezeirpath-in-cglayer) (a previous question by you)

Comment: @Volker, yes, Its made up of paths.

Comment: @David, no its not the duplicate

Comment: @Volker, I am already drawing the previous layer into the new layer

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist, any other solution instead of drawing paths again